# Is it possible to create an "external" iterator class (ie: without access to the original data type)

Tags: c++, iterator, mfc

I am working on a project where it would be useful to create an iterator type for an MFC class `CArray`.

Since `CArray` is part of the MFC libraries I do not have access to this object.

I have not completely got my head around creating iterators, but as far as I am aware, one would usually create an iterator type as a member of the class type for which the iterator corresponds. In other words, access to the class itself is required.

Is it possible to create an iterator "external" to a class. ie: External to the `CArray` class.

Comment: `CArray` is a contiguous memory region, isn’t it? If so, a pointer to its elements *is* a random-access iterator. No need to do any extra work.

Comment: `CArray` should be pretty simple to wrapp in an iterator: All you need is a reference to the original `CArray` object, and the current index for the iterator.

Answer (score 4):

`CArray` is a continuous container. Thus, a simple pointer is a random-access iterator for this container:

```
template<class ...Ts>
auto begin(CArray<Ts...>& arr) noexcept { return &arr[0]; }

template<class ...T>
auto begin(CArray<Ts...> const& arr) noexcept { return &arr[0]; }

template<class ...T>
auto end(CArray<Ts...>& arr) noexcept { return begin(arr) + arr.GetSize(); }

template<class ...T>
auto end(CArray<Ts...> const& arr) noexcept { return begin(arr) + arr.GetSize(); }
```

Comment: So how would you iterate between `begin`/ `end`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle like any other iterator. Those are random-access iterators.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: This returns pointers. Pointers are iterators for contiguous arrays. That is intentional - the definition of iterators is a generalization of pointers.

Comment: @MSalters yes, indeed. That's exactly what I meant to say as well.