# Should the `begin` and `end` functions be overloaded inside the namespace `std`?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

Recently I have been working on a code base which uses MFC and objects such as `CArray<T, U>`.

Some parts of new code which has been written make use of the STL and `<algorithm>` library.

For example

```
CArray<int int> carray;
carray // do stuff
std::vector<int> stlvector(begin(carray), end(carray));
stlvector.dostuff() // do stuff
```

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70308280/is-it-possible-to-create-an-external-iterator-class-ie-without-access-to-the/70308920#70308920) about creating iterators for a class such as `CArray`, which I do not have access to.

I now have some further questions about this. Here is my first question:

- Should the `begin` and `end` functions be inside the `std` namespace?

I will ask the other questions separately and provide links to them shortly, replacing this line of text when those links are available.

Comment: begin and end need template specializations, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin

Comment: _"...Should the begin and end functions be inside the std namespace?..."_ no add them in your own namespace and rely on ADL to find them. See _"...It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: I'd replace `CArray<int int>` with `std::vector<int>` alltogether.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Can't be done

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to look at a non-trivial use of `begin`:

```
CArray<int> carray;
for (auto c : carray){
}
```

The `begin` is hidden in the range-for loop! Which `begin(carray)` is this? The name lookup rules here say that **only** argument-dependent lookup is done. There's no attempt to look at `std::begin`, since `std` is not at all related to `CArray`.

This makes sense. `CArrayIterator begin(CArray)` is a function that belongs to `CArray`, and therefore should be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

To properly define the function, it should be defined in the same namespace as `CArray`. To properly use it generically, it should be used like, similar to the [two-step swap idiom](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/hpqbdz/comment/fxuclpq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

```cpp
{
    using std::begin;
    begin(my_carray);
}
```

---

Alternative you might consider using some C++20 features that can wrap `CArray`, such as `std::span` and `std::ranges::view_interface`